# php-javascript: cannot update the variable

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps-api-3, ebay-api

I'm doing this for an university assignment. I'm doing a web application based on the APIs of eBay and Google Maps. In practice, I make an API call to eBay and I put the results in a table. Now, clicking on the location of each item I got as a result, I want to geocode the address in a Google map. I wrote the PHP code for eBay API and the Javascript code for the Google Maps API as follows:

PHP code for eBay API

```
foreach($resp->searchResult->item as $item){
            $_i = 1;

            // Determine which price to display
            if ($item->sellingStatus->currentPrice) {
                $price = $item->sellingStatus->currentPrice;
            } else {
                $price = $item->listingInfo->buyItNowPrice;
            }

            $itemLocation = $item->location;
            // For each item, create a cell 
            $results .= "<tr> \n<td $thisCellColor valign=\"top\"> \n";
            $results .= "<img src=\"$item->galleryURL\"></td> \n";
            $results .= "<td $thisCellColor valign=\"top\"> <p><a href=\"" . $item->viewItemURL . "\">" . $item->title . "</a></p>\n";
            $results .= 'Shipped to: <b>' . $item->shippingInfo->shipToLocations . "</b><br> \n";
            $results .= 'Current price: <b>$' . $price . "</b><br> \n";
            $results .= "Location: <INPUT TYPE=\"button\" id=\"$_i\" VALUE=\"$itemLocation\" onclick='clickToGeocode($_i);'  <br>";
            $results .= "</FORM> \n";
            $results .= "</td> </tr> \n\n";
            $_i = $_i + 1;
        }
```

Javascript code for Google Maps

```
function clickToGeocode(id){
    var address = document.getElementById(id).value;
    document.write(id);
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: results[0].geometry.location
        });
    } else {
        alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
    });
}
```

The problem is that every time I try to geocode a location the map goes to the location of the first item found in eBay..I mean the `$_i` (in PHP) and the `id` (in Javascript) is always 1..

How can I resolve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're resetting `$_i` to `1` each time. The initial value needs to be set *before* the loop, not *within* it:

```
$_i = 1;

foreach($resp->searchResult->item as $item)
{
```

Comment: @MichaelRushton...what a stupid question I have done..I completly missed this...thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Your html is broken:

```
$results .= "Location: <input [..snip...] onclick='clickToGeocode($_i);'  <br>";
                                                                        ^---- here
```

You never close the `<input>` tag, e.g. you're missing a `>` at the indicated spot.